# How to efficiently transform dataframe to lists discarding nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

What is an efficient way to transform a dataframe to lists? While doing so I want to discard the nan values which results in unequal list sizes.

I can easily transform a dataframe to list of lists with:

`df_sequences = df.values.tolist()`

However it has a lot of nan values which are ok for the dataframe but I don't want them in the lists. So I tried to include numpy as well:

```
test = np.array([[1,2,3],[np.nan,2,3]])
print(test)
print(~numpy.isnan(test))
x = test[~numpy.isnan(test)]
x
```

Unfortunately I did not understand, why the shape is changed in the example above, the output is:

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [nan  2.  3.]]
[[ True  True  True]
 [False  True  True]]
array([1., 2., 3., 2., 3.])
```

And also I don't know if its efficient to apply it over the whole multi dimensional list, maybe there is a way to do it before converting to a list.

Comment: If I understand, if there is a NaN in a row, you want to discard the whole row ?

Comment: No just the nan values from the row/list

Comment: As @gmds said, you canno't have incosistent dimensons in your array. So one solution is to fill NaN values with some value if you don't want the whole row to be throwed. Lastly, you can maybe find an implementation of your algorithm that handle missing values.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of `numpy` arrays (and by extension, `pandas` DataFrames) is that they have consistent dimensions. So, for example, each row will have the same number of columns as every other row.

To do what you want in Python, I think, would require a nested `list` comprehension:

```
[[element for element in row if ~np.isnan(element)] for row in df.values.tolist()]
```

Comment: The reason for this is to use the lists as input for Apriori algorithm, unfortunately I can not insert a df to it

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```py
lists_not_nan = map(lambda row: filter(lambda val: not np.isnan(val), row), df.values)
```